# Due to some reason the bus which is scheduled from Chennai to Bangalore has been postponed for 5 days

Tags: oracle

Due to some reason the bus which is scheduled from Chennai to Bangalore has been postponed for 5 days. Write a query to change the scheduled date to the new date in the schedule table.

This is what I tried...
update schedule set travel_date=to_date(travel_date+5,'DD-MON-YY') where source='Chennai' and destination='Bangalore';

And I am getting 09-MAY-16 but should have get 14-MAY-16.

Comment: Thanks Anuvansh Chauhan.  Is it possible that your update failed due to Bangalore being mispelled?  'Banglore' vs 'Bangalore'?

Comment: My bad I just misspelled it here while writing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `TRAVEL_DATE` column's datatype is `DATE` (it should be), then there's no need for additional functions:

```
update schedule set 
  travel_date = travel_date + 5
where source = 'Chennai' 
  and destination = 'Bangalore';
```

By the way, referencing sources/destinations by name is probably not a very good idea. I live in a small country and there are places that share the same name. I guess that India has the same "problem", but much more possible. In other words: you should reference them by unique codes, not by names.

Comment: It would help if you posted CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, so that we could see what you really have. By the way, did you **COMMIT** after issuing the UPDATE, to save changes you've made?

Comment: Ohh now I get it I should have used other fields. Thanks for your help.

Comment: LOL, yes. We also have a  "problem"  of 2 different names referring to the same place.